# GetValueAt(Int a, int b) which returns int

Tags: java, arrays, int

I have map which is array[][], and I have a method

```
public int[][] getMap(){
   int [][] array = new int[this.size][this.size];
        for(int i=0;i<this.map.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<this.map[i].length;j++)
            {
                array[i][j]=map[j][i];
            }
        }
        return array;
}
```

now I need to rewrite code which is above using just

```
public int getValueAt(int a, int b){}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to implement `getValueInt()`?

Comment: Are you sure of this ? Quite strange question.

Comment: Don't know if this is what you are asking but shouldn't it be: `return this.map[a][b]`

Comment: and what exactly is stopping you?

Comment: how can I rewrite getMap method as int getValueAt(int a, int b)?

Comment: it does not make any sense to do this, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand much what your are trying to achieve, but I think your want to do this:

```
public int getValueAt(int a, int b){
    return this.map[a][b]
}
```

Then you could use the method as:

```
public int[][] getTransformedCopy() {
    int[][] array = new int[this.map.length][this.map[0].length]
    for(int i = 0; i < this.map.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < this.map[0].length; j++) {
              array[i][j] = getValueAt(j, i);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```